# Getting ErrorCode 212 while creating RefreshToken for Intuit QuickBooks through c# code

Tags: c#, integration, intuit-partner-platform, quickbooks-online

I am using following link to generate Refresh token for Intuit QuickBooks integration

https://gist.github.com/IntuitDeveloperRelations/7259345.

but I am getting ErrorCode 212 - "Token Refresh Window Out of Bounds". I am unable to understand what i am doing wrong. I've created intuit account just 15 days back, so there is no question of exceeding 30-day window bounds.

What i am missing here ? What all information do i need to refresh the Token ? Do I need sessionHandle as well ? If yes, how to generate it ?

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Sagar Vyas

Comment: contact intuit support if you feel that is in error.

Answer (score 2):

The 30-day window bound is 30 days *from the expiration of the token*, not 30 days from when you got the token.

Tokens are by default valid for 180 days. That means you can only renew after 150 days of use.

So, you're out of the allowable bounds, just as the error says.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it was quite helpful. I was thinking other way round, it clarified many doubts.